# Python Pandas - turn absolute periods into relative periods

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I want to use to calculate rolling sums relative to an event date. The event date is different for each column and is represented by the latest date in which there is a value in each column.

Here is a toy example:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=8, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({
            '1' : [56, 2, 3, 4, 5, None, None, None],
            '2' : [51, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, None, None],
            '3' : [51, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, None]}, index = rng)

pd.rolling_sum(df,3)
```

The dataframe it produces looks like this:

```
            1       2       3
2011-01-01  NaN     NaN     NaN
2011-01-02  NaN     NaN     NaN
2011-01-03  61      56      56
2011-01-04  9       9       9
2011-01-05  12      12      12
2011-01-06  NaN     15      15
2011-01-07  NaN     NaN     11
2011-01-08  NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I now want to align the last event dates on the final row of the dataframe and set the index to 0 with each preceding row index -1,-2,-3 and so on. The periods no longer being absolute but relative to the event date.

The desired dataframe would look like this:

```
    1   2   3
-7.00   NaN NaN NaN
-6.00   NaN NaN NaN
-5.00   NaN NaN NaN
-4.00   NaN NaN 56
-3.00   NaN 56  9
-2.00   61  9   12
-1.00   9   12  15
0.00    12  15  11
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any easy ways to do this. The following will work, but a bit messy.

```
In [37]: def f(x):
   ....:     y = x.dropna()
   ....:     return Series(y.values,x.index[len(x)-len(y):])
   ....: 

In [40]: roller = pd.rolling_sum(df,3).reset_index(drop=True)

In [41]: roller
Out[41]: 
    1   2   3
0 NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
2  61  56  56
3   9   9   9
4  12  12  12
5 NaN  15  15
6 NaN NaN  11
7 NaN NaN NaN

[8 rows x 3 columns]

In [43]: roller.apply(f).reindex_like(roller)
Out[43]: 
    1   2   3
0 NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN  56
4 NaN  56   9
5  61   9  12
6   9  12  15
7  12  15  11

[8 rows x 3 columns]

In [44]: result = roller.apply(f).reindex_like(roller)

In [49]: result.index = result.index.values-len(result.index)+1

In [50]: result
Out[50]: 
     1   2   3
-7 NaN NaN NaN
-6 NaN NaN NaN
-5 NaN NaN NaN
-4 NaN NaN  56
-3 NaN  56   9
-2  61   9  12
-1   9  12  15
 0  12  15  11

[8 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: FWIW, I've had to reimplement a "faller" like this (what I usually call it) several times.

Comment: was waiting for you to comment! The first part I think could be a nice method actually (would be much more efficient if you do it as a frame). interested? its a variation on dropna, maybe ``df.dropna(kind='furthest',axis=1)`` or something? (or maybe 'faller')