# shifting all the columns in a dataframe to extreme end replacing all nan

Tags: python, pandas

I need to shift all the individual columns in the following dataframe to extreme end. Is there any switch in `shift` function to do that?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[11,22,33,44,55], [nan,44,55], [nan,33,44,55], [11,22]]).T
```

Input

```
11  NaN NaN 11
22  44  33  22
33  55  44  NaN
44  NaN 55  NaN
55  NaN NaN NaN
```

Output

```
11  NaN NaN NaN
22  NaN NaN NaN
33  NaN 33  NaN
44  44  44  11
55  55  55  22
```

Edit: The way I see it is that all the columns are independent and they need to be treated differently. While pushing down, as soon as I get the non-NAN value I need to stop.

I am trying to accomplish this by first converting the dataframe into a list of lists, then insert nans, and in the end, convert back into the dataframe.

Comment: Does the order of values matter?  Could it be 55, 44 or 44,33,55?

Comment: @LiamFoley, Ordering does matter here.

Comment: So, will the lower value always come first, or could that change?

Comment: @LiamFoley, the ordering of the data in each column will remain same. Only thing that changes is that the entire non-zero values percolates down to the bottom.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670904/python-pandas-turn-absolute-periods-into-relative-periods/) and [GH #6713](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6713)-- we simply didn't get around to it. :-/

Comment: What do you expect if there is a `NaN` in the middle of the columns? e.g [0,1,NaN,3,4]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over each col, get the index position of the last valid value and then shift by the length of the df minus this index position, as indexes are 0 based you need to offset by 1:

```
In [33]:

for col in df: 
    idx = df.loc[df[col].notnull(),col].index[-1]
    df[col] = df[col].shift(len(df) - (idx + 1))
df
Out[33]:
    0   1   2   3
0  11 NaN NaN NaN
1  22 NaN NaN NaN
2  33 NaN  33 NaN
3  44  44  44  11
4  55  55  55  22
```

Answer (score 0):

This solutions appends that portion of the dataframe which contains any NaN with the portion that does not.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[11,22,33,44,55], [np.nan,44,55], [np.nan,33,44,55], [11,22]]).T

>>> pd.concat([df.loc[df.isnull().T.any()], df.loc[df.notnull().T.all()]])
    0   1   2   3
0  11 NaN NaN  11
2  33  55  44 NaN
3  44 NaN  55 NaN
4  55 NaN NaN NaN
1  22  44  33  22
```

As your columns are independent, the following should sort each individually and then concatenate the result:

```
df2 = []
for c in df:
    s = df[c].copy()
    s.sort(inplace=True, na_position='first')
    df2.append(s)
result = pd.DataFrame([c.values for c in df2]).T

>>> result
    0   1   2   3
0  11 NaN NaN NaN
1  22 NaN NaN NaN
2  33 NaN  33 NaN
3  44  44  44  11
4  55  55  55  22
```